# sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) fe_sendauth: no password supplied

Tags: postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

i am trying to run this simple flask app  and I keep getting this error in the terminal when trying to run the flask app
`FLASK_APP=app.py flask run`
i keep getting this error : 
`sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) fe_sendauth: no password supplied`

here is my app:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://postgres@localhost:5432/testdb'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
class Person(db.Model):
  __tablename__ = 'persons'
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  name = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)
db.create_all()
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello World!'
```

just to clarify i have psycopg2, flask-SQLAlchemy and all dependencies installed **AND THERE IS NO PASSWORD FOR USER postgres by default** and i haven't changed that and i can log in to database as postgres using psql **without password** without any problems.

Full error output:

```
FLASK_APP=app.py flask run
 * Serving Flask app "app.py"
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py:800: UserWarning: SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True to suppress this warning.
  warnings.warn('SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True to suppress this warning.')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 1122, in _do_get
    return self._pool.get(wait, self._timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/queue.py", line 145, in get
    raise Empty
sqlalchemy.util.queue.Empty
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2147, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 387, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 766, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 516, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 1138, in _do_get
    self._dec_overflow()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 66, in __exit__
    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 187, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 1135, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 333, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 461, in __init__
    self.__connect(first_connect_check=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 651, in __connect
    connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 105, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 393, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/home/aa/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 126, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/aa/.local/bin/flask", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/aa/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 967, in main
    cli.main(args=sys.argv[1:], prog_name="python -m flask" if as_module else None)
  File "/home/aa/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 586, in main
    return super(FlaskGroup, self).main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/aa/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/aa/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/home/aa/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/home/aa/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/aa/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 73, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/aa/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/aa/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 848, in run_command
    app = DispatchingApp(info.load_app, use_eager_loading=eager_loading)
  File "/home/aa/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 305, in __init__
    self._load_unlocked()
  File "/home/aa/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 330, in _load_unlocked
    self._app = rv = self.loader()
  File "/home/aa/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 388, in load_app
    app = locate_app(self, import_name, name)
  File "/home/aa/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 240, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "/home/aa/Desktop/Udacity - FullStackND 2020/FullStackND2020/Practice Projects/flask hello world app/app.py", line 18, in <module>
    db.create_all()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 972, in create_all
    self._execute_for_all_tables(app, bind, 'create_all')
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 964, in _execute_for_all_tables
    op(bind=self.get_engine(app, bind), **extra)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 3934, in create_all
    tables=tables)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1928, in _run_visitor
    with self._optional_conn_ctx_manager(connection) as conn:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 81, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1921, in _optional_conn_ctx_manager
    with self.contextual_connect() as conn:
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2112, in contextual_connect
    self._wrap_pool_connect(self.pool.connect, None),
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2151, in _wrap_pool_connect
    e, dialect, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1465, in _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection
    exc_info
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 203, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 186, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2147, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 387, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 766, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 516, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 1138, in _do_get
    self._dec_overflow()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 66, in __exit__
    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 187, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 1135, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 333, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 461, in __init__
    self.__connect(first_connect_check=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 651, in __connect
    connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 105, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 393, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/home/aa/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 126, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so apparently you need a password to connect to database from SQLAlchemy, I was able to work around this by simply creating a password or adding new user with password.

let me know if there is a different work around/solution

Answer (score 3):

Other than just setting a password, you can log in without a password by:

1. Enable trust authentication, eg `echo "local all all trust" | sudo tee -a /etc/postgresql/10/main/pg_hba.conf`
2. Create a role with login access with the same username as your local username, eg if `whoami` returns `myname`, then `sudo -u postgres psql -c "CREATE ROLE myname WITH LOGIN"`
3. Use sqlalchemy's postgresql unix domain connection instead of tcp ([ref](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/postgresql.html?highlight=postgres%20password#unix-domain-connections)), eg `"postgres+psycopg2://myname@/mydb"`

Note that this requires installing `pip3 install psycopg2-binary`